# Masstransit publish method not giving any negative acknowledgement when the queue size exceeds the maxlength

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using the RabbitMQ message broker using the Masstransit library in c#. Using the Publish method to publish the messages from the producer service. We have added the max length policy(for testing added 1 length) to the queue and trying to publish the more number of messages from the publisher application. After reaching the max length queue is rejecting the messages but, no negative acknowledgement on publish method.

As per the RabbitMQ document, asking to set the 'publisher confirms' but I am unable to do it in Masstransit.

below is the documentation URL :
https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html

I need negative acknowledgement to publish method once queue length reached to maximum.

I tried with different approaches but no luck.